# Should Leave Open votes get converted to reopen votes upon question closure?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I think doing this would be good because the people who have reviewed it and voted to leave it open obviously think that it should stay open. So if at a later time the question gets 5 close votes and ends up being closed it will be difficult for the people to know this and go back to the question to cast their reopen vote.

What does everyone else think about this?

Answer (score 6):

I cannot see how this would work.

If the question is edited in between their review and closure then they may have been reviewing a quite different question.

Even if no edits have been performed prior to closure, the votes of five users or one moderator to close should mean that the case for it being kept open is at least contentious, and the question needs to be improved through editing.

Those edits will change the question that the earlier "stay open" votes were given for.

I think the current behaviour works well to promote high quality rather than questionable quality questions.